# Restricting Access to Kubernetes Ingress using LDAP and VPN

Tags: vpn, ldap, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I'm working on securing access to my Kubernetes cluster, specifically for the domain name xyz.com. Currently, I'm using NGINX Ingress with the nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range annotation to restrict access to a specific IP range.

However, I'm looking for a more robust solution and considering LDAP integration for centralized user authentication and authorization. Additionally, I'm exploring the possibility of using VPN for an added layer of security.

Here are my specific questions:

How can I integrate LDAP with Kubernetes to control access to the Ingress resource based on LDAP user credentials ?

Are there best practices for combining LDAP authentication with VPN access for securing a specific domain within Kubernetes?

What tools or configurations are recommended for implementing LDAP authentication and VPN access in a Kubernetes environment?

I appreciate any guidance or insights into securing access to my Kubernetes cluster and Ingress resources